# Why doesn't "go vendor add" work with a revision number

Tags: go, dependency-management, govendor

I was getting a compile error which led me to believe that I had the wrong version of a library in my vendor folder. The first task was to determine what revision of the library was correct. I needed to find the version of the library source that contained the string "VolumeCreateRequest". For that I used this trick from the root folder of the library:

```
git rev-list --all | xargs git grep VolumeCreateRequest
```

From that I found the version hash: `06f160237426e705ed214a4f087d4aeea32c0a8b`:

So then I tried to add that version into my vendor folder
`go vendor add github.com/docker/docker/...@06f160237426e705ed214a4f087d4aeea32c0a8b`

But it doesn't work. When I check the library's version using git it does *not* report the version I just fetched.

```
git log -n 1 --pretty=format:"%H"
```

The vendor.json file also contains the wrong version

so what's up? After carefully reading the docs I see go vender *add* just silently ignores the `@06f160237426e705ed214a4f087d4aeea32c0a8b` on the end of my fetch URI.

The correct command is go vendor **fetch** which supports the @version

`govendor fetch  github.com/docker/docker/...@06f160237426e705ed214a4f087d4aeea32c0a8b`

Another way to accomplish this is to git checkout the version you want of the library, in your GOPATH (i.e. not in your vendor folder), then `govendor add` the package from your GOPATH

So now I check the git version and we are all good. Then the next problem occurred. Our generate.go file (invoked by `go generate`) is going in and overwriting the desired version in my `vendor.json` with what was on my GOPATH.

The sequence in our `generate.go` is:

```
//go:generate govendor add +external
//go:generate govendor fetch +missing
//go:generate go vendor sync
```

This turned out to be wrong because the add would overwrite my changes, then the sync is ineffectual because vendor.json already infected with wrong version.

The correct sequence is this:

```
//go:generate govendor sync
//go:generate govendor add +external
//go:generate govendor fetch +missing
```

In this way, your customized vendor.json will sync the vendor folder to what is *desired* first, and only *after* that will external and missing dependencies be downloaded.

Finally, several dependencies actually would not compile at all do to platform specific stuff. To cure this, I add these lines in generate.go to remove those broken dependencies, *after* I sync, add, fetch

```
//go:generate govendor remove github.com/docker/docker/runconfig
//go:generate govendor remove github.com/docker/docker/libcontainerd
//go:generate govendor remove github.com/docker/libcompose/test
//go:generate govendor remove github.com/Microsoft/...
```

Comment: Related blog post: [Dave Cheney: Gophers, please tag your releases](http://dave.cheney.net/2016/06/24/gophers-please-tag-your-releases)